# Read attribute of a self closing tag using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

How can I read the attribute of self closing tag in an XML document using pure javascript?
eg. get value of "url" in the xml element below?

```
<channel>     
  <item> 
    <title>News Title Goes Here<title>
    <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/80270000/jpg/_80270552_mjadzelics_cleared_07.jpg"/> 
  </item>  
<channel>
```

The javascript call **getElementsByTagName** works on the title node, but not on the self closing media:thumbnail node

Comment: Is it parsed as RSS, or are you accessing it like HTML ?

Comment: Note that the tagname is `media:thumbnail` not `media` !

Comment: It's not the JavaScript you need to worry about, it's the document parsing engine you're using. Are you doing this in a browser? The problem is the `media` namespace, in which case you'll need a namespace-aware engine.

Comment: I was trying to parse the document as an xml document using the following call: var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET",'http://feeds.feedburner.com/engadget/Dnjv',false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

Comment: @Mouser — What? [Self-closing tag syntax was created for XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e2480)! You can only use them in XML! (HTML has (some) elements with optional or forbidden end tags, and HTML 5 allows people addicted to XML to stick a `/` in the start tag)

Comment: I would think feedburner supports CORS, but running the link you posted it does not include CORS headers, and is stopped by the same origin policy. A workaround could be to use Google Feed API, which can actually return JSON, which makes things simpler, but if you're getting the content, that's probably not an issue ?

Comment: You may find the answer [here to be enlightening](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7257088/215552)...

Answer (score 0):

I was working with this as a string... idk what approach you're taking, but this should help.

you aren't closing your title tag, is one thing.

xml fix:

```
<title>News Title Goes Here</title>
```

js

```
var xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml").querySelectorAll('[url]'),
    mediaEls = ([].slice.call(xml)).filter(function(a) { return a.tagName == 'media:thumbnail'}),
    urls = mediaEls.map(function(a, i) { return a.getAttribute('url') });
console.log(urls); 
// ["http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/80270000/jpg/_80270552_mjadzelics_cleared_07.jpg"]
```

Comment: Im getting 't' is undefined. Can you please advise what should replace this?

Comment: lol. yeah, left my test var name in there: `t`. check the edit... it was supposed to be `xml`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access the property using a different method. The javascript xml call I used was getElementsByTagNameNS, but for older IE browsers, I fell back to getElementsByTagName call.

See implementation code below.

```
function getElementsByTagNameNS(xml, namespace, prefix, tag)
{
    return xml.getElementsByTagNameNS ? xml.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, tag) : xml.getElementsByTagName(prefix + ':' + tag);
}
```

To use this:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
var imgUrl = x.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "thumbnail").getAttribute("url");
```

Comment: The feed I was trying to access was BBC RSS XML Feed ([link]http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int). For anyone interested in consuming this feed in pure javascript, visit the following link ([link]http://www.favour4u.com/) for a full implementation and view source on the .js file